# Unicorn server crashing worker with minimal backtrace

Tags: ruby, gdb, unicorn

I'm experiencing unicorn server worker random crash with this backtrace. I got it via gdb (bt command) and core dump.

```
#0  0x00007f2f525830c2 in select () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2f5343025c in thread_timer () from /usr/lib64/libruby19.so.1.9
#2  0x00007f2f530d0047 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f2f5258928d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Any ideas how to get more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas how to get more info?

This is probably *not* the thread you are looking for (some *other* thread has crashed).

This GDB command may help you find that other thread: `thread apply all where`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. There's no info in other threads, but this is exactly what I was asking for!